# How does get function typecheck in lens

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, lenses

I have been reading [this post](http://www.twanvl.nl/blog/haskell/cps-functional-references) to understand lens. They initially define a
type synonym like this:

```
type RefF a b = forall f. Functor f => (b -> f b) -> (a -> f a)
```

Const is defined like this:

```
newtype Const a b = Const { getConst :: a }
```

How does the `get` function typecheck:

```
get :: RefF a b -> a -> b
get r = getConst . r Const
```

The type of getConst is something like this:

```
getConst :: Const a b -> a
```

The type of `r Const` which I guess is something like this:

```
r Const = (b -> f b) -> (Const -> f Const)
```

Then how does both `getConst` and `r Const` get's composed to give `a -> b`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The type of `r` is obtained by substituting the const functor for `f`; since we'll need a `b` result that has to be the first argument (only `x` is actually found in the `Const x y` type)

```
    r :: (b -> Const b b) -> (a -> Const b a)
```

Now the argument is simple: that's merely the `Const` constructor.

```
    r Const :: a -> Const b a
```

And if you post-compose that with `getConst :: Const b a -> b`, you end up with

```
    getConst . r Const :: a -> b
```

Comment: Thanks, Is `r Const` partial function application ?

Comment: Sure. But you should consider the signature of `RefF` literally as: a function that maps a function to a function (or maybe: a function that maps a morphism to a morphism). That is of course equivalent to saying "that maps a function and a value to a value", but it makes clearer what's going on, as J. Abrahamson nicely explained.

Answer (score 4):

One way to understand the type of a Lens

```
type Lens s a = forall f . Functor f => (a -> f a) -> (s -> f s)
```

is to read it as "if you tell me how to put the (focused) subpart into some `Functor` I can tell you how to put the whole thing into that `Functor`". The `forall` means that the person *using* the lens gets to choose the `Functor`, though, so we can play tricks.

The `Const` `Functor` is a trick `Functor` in that it has two type parameters, but while it's `Functor`ial over the second one... it actually only contains a value of the first.

```
newtype Const real fake = Const { getConst :: real }
```

Thus, the constructor `Const` is a function

```
Const :: real -> Const real fake
```

which secrets away the real value being wrapped and results in a `Functor` which pretends to be carrying any type `fake` whatsoever.

---

To be clear, the `Functor` instance for `Const` looks like

```
instance Functor (Const b) where
  fmap _ (Const b) = Const b
```

in other words, `fmap` is essentially a no-op.

---

So let's see what happens when we pass `Const` to a lens:

```
l       :: Lens s a
Const   :: a -> Const a a
l Const :: s -> Const a s
```

In other words, our Lens got tricked into injecting the subpart, `a`, into `Const` and ignoring the whole-part, `s`. Then we just extract it with `getConst`.

```
getConst :: Const real fake -> real

getConst . l Const :: s -> a
```